# Error when trying to display listViews with Cursor Window Null Exception error

Tags: android

I m trying to add goal Date to listgDitem, goal Weight to listgWitem and current Weight to listcWitem and insert them to the Sqlite and display them in historyActivity.java. Inserting data in the settingsActivity works but displaying these items are showing following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2
>   from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly
>   before accessing data from it.
>           at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>           at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
>           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>           at com.example.fftest.historyActivity.viewData(historyActivity.java:121)
>           at com.example.fftest.historyActivity.onCreate(historyActivity.java:85)

historyActivity.java

```
public class historyActivity extends MainActivity {
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    ListView listView1;
    ListView listView2;
    ListView listView3;

    ArrayList<String> listgDitem;
    ArrayList<String> listgWitem;
    ArrayList<String> listcWitem;
Cursor cursor;
EditText goalDinput;
    EditText goalWinput;
    EditText currentWinput;


    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(historyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_history:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_history);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(historyActivity.this, historyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_progress:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_progress);
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(historyActivity.this, progressActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_settings:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_settings);
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(historyActivity.this, settingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        goalDinput = findViewById(R.id.goaldinput);
        goalWinput = findViewById(R.id.goalwinput);
        currentWinput = findViewById(R.id.currentWinput);

        listView1=findViewById(R.id.goaldlistView);
        listView2=findViewById(R.id.goalwlistView);
        listView3=findViewById(R.id.currentwlistView);
        viewData();
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = listView1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(historyActivity.this,"" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = listView2.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(historyActivity.this,"" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        listView3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = listView3.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(historyActivity.this,"" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void viewData() {
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listgDitem=new ArrayList<>();
        listgWitem=new ArrayList<>();
        listcWitem=new ArrayList<>();

        cursor = myDB.viewData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listgDitem.add(cursor.getString(1));
                listgWitem.add(cursor.getString(2));
               listcWitem.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_history, listgDitem);
            adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_history, listgWitem);
            adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_history, listcWitem);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            listView3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        }
    }


}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.fftest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME="weightDB.db";
    public static final String DB_TABLE="weightDB_data";

    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String Col1 = "GDATE";
    public static final String Col2 = "GWEIGHT";
    public static final String Col3 = "CWEIGHT";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ("+
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
             " GDATE TEXT, GWEIGHT TEXT, CWEIGHT " + ") ";
    Cursor cursor;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, 1);}


    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS "  + DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String gDate, String gWeight, String cWeight){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Col1, gDate);
        contentValues.put(Col2, gWeight);
        contentValues.put(Col3, cWeight);

        long result = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        return result !=-1;
    }

    public Cursor viewData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * from " + DB_TABLE;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return cursor;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things I could see as suspicious/error in your code,

1.If you recently changed the `CREATE_TABLE` schema, you have to update the DB Version at your `DatabaseHelper.java`

```
static final int DB_VERSION = 2;


public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

2.Incomplete CREATE_TABLE schema found, the last part, type `TEXT` for `CWEIGHT` in the `CREATE_TABLE` missed.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ("+
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
         " GDATE TEXT, GWEIGHT TEXT, CWEIGHT " + ") ";
```

Correct one is,

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ("+
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
         " GDATE TEXT, GWEIGHT TEXT, CWEIGHT TEXT" + "); ";
```

3.onUpgrade() method with incorrect  schema noticed, the "IF" position,

```
db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS "  + DB_TABLE);
```

This may throw an error like below,

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IF": syntax error
```

Correct syntax is DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]table_name;
So you may update your code with,

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "  + DB_TABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, corrected that one. I m getting the Null Exception Error for line 121 in historyActivity.java for                 listgWitem.add(cursor.getString(2));

Comment: Have you recently changed the SQL Schema?

Comment: If so Increase the DB version at         super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, 2);}, I doubt your cursor has only 2 columns.

Comment: Updated my answer. please check.

Comment: I have 3 columns.

Comment: Ok, You have 3 columns + one auto increment _ID column, I doubted, you have changed the CREATE_TABLE schema and not updated the DB_VERSION, issue happens such cases, my statement is based on that assumption. If the issue is not fixed even after you increased the DB_VERSION, then i am wrong in this case.

Comment: I incremented the version , still same issue.

Comment: Was that the same error as before ?  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow" or a new one. I expect that will be a new error as I see your onUpgrade() has an issue.